# Cannot add a class field to ArrayList

Tags: java, oop

I have no idea how to properly write line of code adding class field to an ArrayList

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        zapisz("BazaDanych.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        FilmExtended filmExtended = new FilmExtended();
        ArrayList<FilmExtended> bazaFilmow = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 0;
        while(scanner.nextInt()!= 0)
        {
            boolean check = true;
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Podaj tytuł fimu: ");
                String temp = scanner.nextLine();
                if (temp.matches("[a-zA-Z]{2,}"));
                {
                    bazaFilmow.add(i,filmExtended.setTytul(temp));
                    check = false;
                }
            }while (check);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you always add in index `0` increment your i and does filmExtended.setTytul(temp)  return FilmExtended?

Comment: Related [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    zapisz("BazaDanych.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<FilmExtended> bazaFilmow = new ArrayList<>();
    //remove index
    while(scanner.nextInt() != 0)
    {
        boolean check = true;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Podaj tytuł fimu: ");
            String temp = scanner.nextLine();
            if (temp.matches("[a-zA-Z]{2,}"));
            {
                FilmExtended filmExtended = new FilmExtended(); //create new instance
                filmExtended.setTytul(temp);
                bazaFilmow.add(filmExtended); //use add without index or else need to increment your index
                check = false;
            }
        } while (check);

} }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed? And why this solves the issue? Else your answer isnt that helpful, see [answer] thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't increment your index `i`. It's always `0`. You have to put `i++;` in your do while loop

Comment: i did but it wasn't written in this part of code i pasted

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `i++;` in the do while loop

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to fix it:

1. `filmExtended.setTytul(temp)` should return `this`.
2. `i++` or remove `i`